# Map QComboBox to a column of a MySQL table, possible?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qt5, c++14

The [`QStringListModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html) can be mapped to [`QComboBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html). And a MySQL table can be mapped by a [`QSqlTableModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html).

I would like to map a `QComboBox` to a column of a MySQL table, so that changes in the database will reflect in the `QComboBox` itens.

What came to my mind is to watch for changes in the database and reload the `QComboBox` itens every time. Is this the best approach?

Comment: Why down voting the question?

Comment: no question asked and nothing tried

Comment: Please read about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `QSqlTableModel` or a `QSqlQueryModel` and set it to the combobox with `QComboBox::setModel()`. You can choose what table column (or query column) display using `QComboBox::setModelColumn()`.

However, it's up to you to update the model when the table is changed (eg with a query), because the `QSqlTableModel` can't automatically update itself when the table contents change.